# Vs code tracking all my files,Source control showing all my files from downloads

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I'm a newbie.
started using git and made my first repo on downloads, now my Vscode is tracking all my files from downloads.
I'm struck.
having no idea about how to resolve this issue :(

**this pic shows my issue**

[image: Vscode]

Comment: Create a Git repo in a separate folder. To remove the Git tracking from your Downloads folder, delete the (hidden) .git directory inside.

Comment: are you unable to make a screenshot with your OS?

Comment: @rioV8 oh ,I'm sorry for that,I correctted my mistake now  and added a screenshot of my issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init